# Ruby increment (+=) raises error undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

The following code is causing me issues:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(n=0)
    @n = n
  end

  attr_accessor :n

  def inc
    n+=1
  end
end
```

Calling `Foo.new.inc` raises `NoMethodError: undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`
Calling `Foo.new.n` returns `0`

Why does `Foo.new.inc` raise an error? I can do `Foo.new.n+=1` with no problem.

Comment: So use `@n`, then? Or `self.n`?

Comment: `n += x` expands to `n = n + x` where *n is bound as a local variable* because it appears on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

tldr; some form of `self.n = x` must *always* be used to assign to a *setter*.

Consider that `n += x` expands to `n = n + x` where *n is bound as a local variable* because it appears on the left-hand side of an assignment. This "introduction" of a local variable counteracts the normal fall-back behavior of an implicit method call (e.g. `n` -> `self.n`) upon self.

Thus, since `n` has not been assigned yet (but it is *bound* as a local variable now), the expression *evaluates as* `n = nil + x` which is what causes the exception to be raised.

Comment: even if you didn't assign to `n`, where would you read from? `ReferenceError`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Whoops, it would be a NameError if `n` was used prior to *any* assignment. I removed the incorrect last paragraph.

Comment: "normal fall-back behavior of an implicit self method call" - reference please? I'm pretty sure this only works for `Kernel`.

Comment: @JanDvorak If there is an identifier, say, `n` that is *not* a local/lexical variable then, where it does *not* appear on the left-hand side of an assignment, it is treated as `self.n` (an implicit self method call).

Comment: Where is this documented? This behavior is new to me (but confirmed by my tests)

Comment: @JanDvorak I have no idea :(

Comment: (also, it appears to be a bad style for the exact reason you can't call writers this way)

Comment: @JanDvorak Using `self.n += x` will work: whenever a setter is used it *must* be invoked upon an explicit receiver such (e.g. self). It's just something to keep in mind when using Ruby. (On the other hand, a language like Python requires an explicit receiver for *every* method call.)

Comment: @JanDvorak: it's not bad style. On the contrary, it's used *everywhere*.

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
def inc
  self.n += 1
end
```

or this

```
def inc
  @n += 1
end
```

In your case, naked name "n" is interpreted as a local variable (which does not exist). You need to specify explicitly that it is a method (`self.n`) or use underlying instance variable.

Comment: `self.n` will only work if `@n` has a reader _and_ a writer (and they behave as expected). I assume the latter form is the preferred one?

Comment: @minitech it does that in _this_ case, but I'm afraid this would be  a rather unusual occurence. I, for one, would make `@n` unwritable.

Comment: I'd mark both answers write if I could. Not sure why I missed the obvious solution, but it definitely threw me for a loop